# How can I load & re-edit previously created icon files in asset studio of android studio which was created by asset studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-icons, android-asset-studio

I have created an icon with asset studio of android studio and some corresponding files were created.

How can I reload those files of that icon in asset studio and re-edit them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I create a new image asset in the Android Studio, then it opens the previously edited version of the image asset automatically. Thus, I can re-edit previously created icon files in the asset studio of the Android Studio.